# Creating a protocol that represents hashable objects that can be on or off

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, type-erasure, hashable

I'm trying to create a simple protocol that says whether or not an object is in an "on" state or an "off" state. The interpretation of what that is depends on the implementing object. For a `UISwitch`, it's whether the switch is on or off (duh). For a `UIButton`, it could be whether the button is in the `selected` state or not. For a `Car`, it could be whether the car's engine is on or not, or even if it is moving or not. So I set out to create this simple protocol:

```
protocol OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool
    func isInOffState() -> Bool
}
```

Now I can extent the aforementioned UI controls like so:

```
extension UISwitch: OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool { return on }
    func isInOffState() -> Bool { return !on }
}

extension UIButton: OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool { return selected }
    func isInOffState() -> Bool { return !selected }
}
```

Now I can make an array of these kinds of objects and loop over it checking whether they are on or off:

```
let booleanControls: [OnOffRepresentable] = [UISwitch(), UIButton()]
booleanControls.forEach { print($0.isInOnState()) }
```

Great! Now I want to make a dictionary that maps these controls to a `UILabel` so I can change the text of the label associated with the control when the control changes state. So I go to declare my dictionary:

```
var toggleToLabelMapper: [OnOffRepresentable : UILabel] = [:]
// error: type 'OnOffRepresentable' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

Oh! Right! Silly me. Ok, so let me just update the protocol using protocol composition (after all, the controls I want to use here are all Hashable: UISwitch, UIButton, etc):

```
protocol OnOffRepresentable: Hashable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool
    func isInOffState() -> Bool
}
```

But now I get a new set of errors:

```
error: protocol 'OnOffRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
error: using 'OnOffRepresentable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported
```

Ok... So I do some stack overflow digging and searching. I find many articles that seem promising, like [Set and protocols in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189345/set-and-protocols-in-swift), [Using some protocol as a concrete type conforming to another protocol is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503602/using-some-protocol-as-a-concrete-type-conforming-to-another-protocol-is-not-sup), and I see that there are some great articles out there on `type erasure` that seem to be exactly what I need: http://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings, http://robnapier.net/erasure, and https://realm.io/news/type-erased-wrappers-in-swift/ just to name a few.

This is where I get stuck though. I've tried reading through all these, and I've tried to create a class that will be `Hashable` and also conform to my `OnOffRepresentable` protocol, but I can't figure out how to make it all connect.

Comment: I first attempted to mimic the version from krakendev, but I got hung up on the fact that the `MythicalType` protocol was the only protocol he was trying to conform to. So when I try substituting `MythicalType` directly for my `OnOffRepresentable` it's not enough. I can't figure out how to jam the `Hashable` part into it. The same applied for Rob Napier's blog, ... maybe. His `Animal` protocol is generic on a `Food` associatedtype, but that's not quite what I'm doing either. The realm.io examples seemed like they'd be best, but `SequenceType` is also very different from my specific needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I'd necessarily make the `OnOffRepresentable` protocol inherit from `Hashable`. It doesn't seem like something that you'd want to be represented as on or off *must* also be hashable. So in my implementation below, I add the `Hashable` conformance to the type erasing wrapper only. That way, you can reference `OnOffRepresentable` items directly whenever possible (without the "can only be used in a generic constraint" warning), and only wrap them inside the `HashableOnOffRepresentable` type eraser when you need to place them in sets or use them as dictionary keys.

```
protocol OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool
    func isInOffState() -> Bool
}

extension UISwitch: OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool { return on }
    func isInOffState() -> Bool { return !on }
}

extension UIButton: OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool { return selected }
    func isInOffState() -> Bool { return !selected }
}

struct HashableOnOffRepresentable : OnOffRepresentable, Hashable {

    private let wrapped:OnOffRepresentable
    private let hashClosure:()->Int
    private let equalClosure:Any->Bool

    var hashValue: Int {
        return hashClosure()
    }

    func isInOnState() -> Bool {
        return wrapped.isInOnState()
    }

    func isInOffState() -> Bool {
        return wrapped.isInOffState()
    }

    init<T where T:OnOffRepresentable, T:Hashable>(with:T) {
        wrapped = with
        hashClosure = { return with.hashValue }
        equalClosure = { if let other = $0 as? T { return with == other } else { return false } }
    }
}

func == (left:HashableOnOffRepresentable, right:HashableOnOffRepresentable) -> Bool {
    return left.equalClosure(right.wrapped)
}

func == (left:HashableOnOffRepresentable, right:OnOffRepresentable) -> Bool {
    return left.equalClosure(right)
}

var toggleToLabelMapper: [HashableOnOffRepresentable : UILabel] = [:]

let anySwitch = HashableOnOffRepresentable(with:UISwitch())
let anyButton = HashableOnOffRepresentable(with:UIButton())

var switchLabel:UILabel!
var buttonLabel:UILabel!

toggleToLabelMapper[anySwitch] = switchLabel
toggleToLabelMapper[anyButton] = buttonLabel
```

Comment: This is really close. I think there's something wrong with the `equalClosure` though. If you instantiate actual `UILabels` and store them in the dictionary and then try to extract the label you just stored, it's always nil. Which makes me think the == operator isn't working as intended.

Comment: @TimFuqua. Good catch! I fixed the == function and added an additional overload so you can compare directly with an unwrapped instance of the protocol. I think that should fix the issue, but I'm typing this on my phone and haven't verified in a playground yet

Comment: There we go! Yeah, I figured it was a simple fix, but I wasn't sure exactly what. Very nice answer. And it's a good, straightforward approach and example to reference again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a protocol with an `associatedType` (or conforming it to another protocol that has an `associatedType` like `Hashable`) will make that protocol very unfriend with generics.

I'll suggest you a very  simple workaround

### OnOffRepresentable

First of all we don't need 2 functions that say exactly the opposite right? ;)

So this

```
protocol OnOffRepresentable {
    func isInOnState() -> Bool
    func isInOffState() -> Bool
}
```

becomes this

```
protocol OnOffRepresentable {
    var on: Bool { get }
}
```

and of course

```
extension UISwitch: OnOffRepresentable { }

extension UIButton: OnOffRepresentable {
    var on: Bool { return selected }
}
```

### Pairing a OnOffRepresentable to a UILabel

Now we can't use `OnOffRepresentable` as `Key` of a `Dictionary` because our protocol must be `Hashable`. Then let's use another data structure!

```
let elms: [(OnOffRepresentable, UILabel)] = [
    (UISwitch(), UILabel()),
    (UIButton(), UILabel()),
]
```

That's it.

Comment: From the beginning, I knew I could already do an array of `OnOffRepresentables`. That's not the point though. I needed them to be `Hashable` for easy lookup in a dictionary. Linearly searching through an array of pairs to find your exact `OnOffRepresentable` control is not optimal and doesn't scale well. That is why a dictionary was mentioned in the example. And I'm indifferent about changing the 2 functions to 2 computed properties (yes, 2, because I'm the kind of dev that prefers using `off` over `!on`, so I'd implement an `off` property as well.