# Is it possible to make a Heterogeneous Set in Swift?

Tags: swift, set

Consider this example:

```
protocol Observable: Hashable {
    // ...
}

struct People: Observable {
    var name: String
    var age: Double

    var hashValue: Int {
        // ...
    }

    static func ==(lhs: People, rhs: People) -> Bool {
        // ,,,
    }
}

struct Color: Observable {
    var red: Double, green: Double, blue: Double

    var hashValue: Int {
        // ...
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Color, rhs: Color) -> Bool {
        // ...
    }
}

var observers: Set<Observable> = [] // Not allowed by the compiler
```

People and Color are both conform to `Observable` protocol which also inherit from `Hashable` protocol. I want to store these inside the `observers` set.

```
using 'Observable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 
'Hashable' is not supported
```

Is it possible to do heterogenous Set in Swift?

Comment: Why don't you just use a set of `AnyHashable`?

Comment: "It works if I do this using Array", I got the following error: `error: protocol 'Observable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
var observers: Array<Observable> = []`

Comment: @AhmadF you're right, sorry about that. I edited the question. But how to make Heterogenous Set anyway?

Comment: `var observers: Set<AnyHashable> = []`

Comment: @LeoDabus because I want to limit the elements only for object / struct that conforms to `Observable` protocol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set and protocols in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189345/set-and-protocols-in-swift).

Comment: As discussed in WWDC 2015 (Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift), by using `Self`, the compiler is going to force us to make it Homogenous Array, and for this example, this is really restrictive. Is there really no way?

Comment: The problem is (as in the linked Q&A) that you can compare two People or two Colors, but you cannot compare a People with a Color.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43263352/2976878

Comment: @Hamish Solved, I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is a way to make it possible.** (Inspired by Apple's implementation)

Before we begin, this is what we want to build.

```
protocol Observer: Hashable {
    associatedtype Sender: Observable

    func valueDidChangeInSender(_ sender: Sender, keypath: String, newValue: Any)
}
```

The source of this problem is the use of `Self` that force the array to be Homogenous. You can see it here:

[image: without self and with self comparison]

**The most important change is that it stop the protocol from being usable as a type.**

That makes us can't do:

```
var observers: [Observer] = [] // Observer is not usable as a type.
```

Therefore, we need another way to make it work.

**We don't do**

```
var observers: [AnyHashable] = []
```

Because `AnyHashable` will not constrain the object to conform `Observer` protocol. Instead, we can wrap the `Observer` object in the `AnyObserver` wrapper like this:

```
var observers: [AnyObserver] = []
observers.append(AnyObserver(yourObject))
```

This will make sure the value of `AnyObserver` struct conforms to `Observer` protocol.

**According to WWDC 2015: Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift**, we can make a bridge with `isEqual(_:)` method so we can compare two `Any`. This way the object doesn't have to conform to `Equatable` Protocol.

```
protocol AnyObserverBox {
    var hashValue: Int { get }
    var base: Any { get }

    func unbox<T: Hashable>() -> T

    func isEqual(to other: AnyObserverBox) -> Bool
}
```

**After that, we make the box that conforms to** `AnyObserverBox`.

```
struct HashableBox<Base: Hashable>: AnyObserverBox {
    let _base: Base

    init(_ base: Base) {
        _base = base
    }

    var base: Any {
        return _base
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return _base.hashValue
    }

    func unbox<T: Hashable>() -> T {
        return (self as AnyObserverBox as! HashableBox<T>)._base
    }

    func isEqual(to other: AnyObserverBox) -> Bool {
        return _base == other.unbox()
    }
}
```

This box contains the actual value of the `AnyObserver` that we will create later.

**Finally we make the** `AnyObserver`.

```
struct AnyObserver {
    private var box: AnyObserverBox

    public var base: Any {
        return box.base
    }

    public init<T>(_ base: T) where T: Observer {
        box = HashableBox<T>(base)
    }
}

extension AnyObserver: Hashable {
    static func ==(lhs: AnyObserver, rhs: AnyObserver) -> Bool {
        // Hey! We can do a comparison without Equatable protocol.
        return lhs.box.isEqual(to: rhs.box)
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return box.hashValue
    }
}
```

**With all of that in place, we can do:**

```
var observers: [AnyObserver] = []
observers.append(AnyObserver(yourObject))
```

Comment: This is the same technique as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/43263352/2976878, a type eraser (might as well close as dupe in that case?). Although note that your current implementation will crash when attempting to use `==` on two  `AnyObserver` instances with different base types as you're force casting to `HashableBox<T>`. You should use conditional casting there (i.e `as?` and return a `T?`).

Comment: I used the same technique as Apple `AnyHashable` showed in Swift open source. I didn't mean to copy your answer as I didn't see your answer when creating this. You're right it will crash, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I wasn't saying you copied my answer (far from it; as you point out, your implementation is based on Swift's `AnyHashable` implementation using a protocol to do the type erasing, whereas mine uses closures) :) I was just saying that they're both valid ways to type erase the underlying concrete type of a `Hashable` instance that conforms to a given protocol (probably could've phrased my first comment better).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *cannot* declare a Set -or even an array- of type `Observable`, that's because at some level `Observable` represents a generic protocol:

Observable -> Hashable -> **Equatable**:

which contains:

> public static func ==(lhs: **Self**, rhs: **Self**) -> Bool

That's the reason why of the inability of using it in *Heterogenous* way. Furthermore, you can't declare an *existential* type:

```
var object: Observable?
// error: protocol 'Observable' can only be used as a generic constraint
// because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

If you are wondering what's the reason of this constraint, I assume that it is logical to compare tow `People` or tow `Color`, but *not* comparing `People` with `Color`.

**So, what can we do?**

As a workaround, you could let your set to be a set of [*AnyHashable*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyhashable) structure (as @Leo mentioned in the comment):

> The AnyHashable type forwards equality comparisons and hashing
>   operations to an underlying hashable value, hiding its specific
>   underlying type.

As follows:

```
let people = People(name: "name", age: 101)
let color = Color(red: 101, green: 101, blue: 101)

var observers: Set<AnyHashable> = []

observers.insert(people)
observers.insert(color)

for (index, element) in observers.enumerated() {
    if element is People {
        print("\(index): people")
    }
}
```

that would be legal.

Comment: That breaks the constraint that the Set should only contain Object that conform to `Observable` protocol. The closest thing would be make a new struct named `AnyObservable` that conforms to `Observable` protocol.